# Using a Sprite Image for Search Box Input Button

Tags: html, css, input, search-box

**EDIT:** You can see the search box [live here](http://pages.whatthenerd.com/).

Before I explain, let me show you the code I am using:

**HTML**

```
<div class="SiteSearch">
    <form action="/search" id="searchform" method="get">
        <input x-webkit-speech="" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="gText" name="q" id="q" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" value ='' "search" placeholder="Search.."/>
        <input type="submit" id="gBtn"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Head .SiteSearch {
  top: 12px;
  right: 0;
}

#Head .SiteSearch {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

input#gText {
  float: left;
  width: 225px;
  height: 23px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px #D9D9D9;
  border-top: solid 1px silver;
  border-right: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}

#searchform #gBtn {
  background-image: url('search.png');
  width: 31px;
  height: 27px;
}

#gBtn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -999px;
  color: transparent;
  background-position: 0 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}

input#gBtn:hover {
  background-position: 31px 0;
  border: none;
}
```

**This is how the search box looks on IE7 vs. IE8/IE9:**

[image: Imgur] vs. [image: Imgur]

As you can see above, the input button image isn't being shown in IE7. How can I fix this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: looks working to me (tested on IETester with debugbar) have you changed anything in the meanwhile?

Comment: @Eliran Malka : Yeah, I fixed it just now. Sharing the answer now. :)

Comment: oh great, cause i started yelling at the IE cache.

Comment: @EliranMalka : lol! (Answer added by the way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I fixed it by modifying the CSS code like so:**

```
#Head .SiteSearch {
  top: 12px;
  right: 0;
}

#Head .SiteSearch {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

input#gText {
  float: left;
  width: 225px;
  height: 23px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px #D9D9D9;
  border-top: solid 1px silver;
  border-right: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}

/* REMOVED THIS PIECE
  #searchform #gBtn {
  background-image: url('search.png');
  width: 31px;
  height: 27px;
}*/

#gBtn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  text-indent: -999px;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: url('search.png'); /* ADDED */
  background-position: 0 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}

input#gBtn:hover {
  background-image: url('search.png'); /* ADDED - BUT OPTIONAL */
  background-position: 31px 0;
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write `background` instead of b`ackground-image` in  your `#gBtn` button. May be that's work

Comment: Doing so seems to break the 'hover' style. You can take a look at it live [here](http://pages.whatthenerd.com/)